# Flavour effects in decaying heavy neutrinos

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, leptogenesis

In “Leptogenesis with heavy neutrino flavours: from density matrix to Boltzmann equations,” [arXiv:1112.4528](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4528), the authors work with heavy right-handed neutrinos $N_i$, that may decay into leptons $l_i$, which are in turn coherent superpositions of lepton flavour states:
\begin{alignat}{2}\label{eq:heavy_neutrino_states_1}
&|l_i\rangle \quad = \sum_{\alpha = e,\mu,\tau} \langle l_\alpha |l_i\rangle|l_\alpha\rangle \quad \equiv \sum_{\alpha = e,\mu,\tau} \mathcal{C}_{i\alpha}|l_\alpha\rangle, \quad \quad \mathcal{C}_{i\alpha} = \langle l_\alpha|l_i\rangle
\, ,\\
&|\overline{l}_i\rangle \quad = \sum_{\alpha = e,\mu,\tau} \langle\overline{l}_\alpha|\overline{l}_i\rangle|\overline{l}_\alpha\rangle \quad \equiv \sum_{\alpha = e,\mu,\tau} \overline{\mathcal{C}}_{i\alpha}|\overline{l}_\alpha\rangle, \quad \quad \overline{\mathcal{C}}_{i\alpha} = \langle\overline{l}_\alpha|\overline{l}_i\rangle \, .
\end{alignat}
where $\mathcal{C}_{i\alpha}$ denote amplitudes. They imply that if $\overline{\mathcal{C}}_{i\alpha} \neq \mathcal{C}_{i\alpha}^*$ then leptons and antileptons have different flavour compositions. Why is that? Shouldn't that be the case for $\overline{\mathcal{C}}_{i\alpha} \neq \mathcal{C}_{i\alpha}$  instead?

Comment: Rather than just stating the number of what I can only assume is an ArXiv paper, it would be better to state the article name and author if possible or to provide an actual link to this paper

Comment: Completely forgot to do so, I apologize. I've now provided the link. Thank you.